# Trigger a process before restart or shutdown

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi
I have a framework which consists of an App, a Load Balancer and a Listener (all of these are written in vb.net 4.5 framework). Load Balancer is running on a server then I have about 9 machines each of which have Listener running on them. Load Balancer assigns the job to a machine. Listener on the machine picks this job up and starts the app to complete the job. At the end of a job, Listener restarts the machine. Before it restarts the machine, it updates its status to ‘Restarting’ (in a XML file) so that Load Balancer knows that this machine is out of commission and does not assign any work to that machine.
My question is, if someone accidentally or for whatever reason, machine reboots (and the reboot is not triggered by the Listener), the XML file is not updated as Listener is killed in the middle of … well listening. Is there a way to trigger some form of script that would update the XML file before machine restarts/reboots/shutsdown?

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-architect how this works. Either the listeners should report back to keep alive their connection or the load balancer should try to talk to the listeners every so often to see if it is available. Relying on an xml file won't work for all scenarios i.e. someone pulls the power plug

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure how load balancer would talk to the listener directly. Could you elaborate as to how I can achieve that please? bearing in mind that listener and load balancer are not on the same machine but are on the same network. Thanks

Comment: Without seeing any of your code - it's quite difficult to give any more than that, but basically you send a message every so often and if you get a response you know that the machine is there.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll look into that